# What is the best way to install a .bin file using default installer options?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm working on a small shell script to set up my development environment (eclipse + java + a bunch of other stuff) on linux. Installing .bin files is among them - these launch a GUI installer where user input is necessary - how do I simply use the default installer options and force the installation to complete?

Comment: /me wonders if NARQ trumps OT...

Answer (score 0):

You can try running them from a terminal passing the '-h', '--help' or '--usage' arguments to see if they handle it (and provide the listing of commands you can give it), but if it wasn't designed to receive any parameters there won't be much you can do for it.